# Javascript: input value sum jumps to max value on mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, html

The title sums it up. I'm trying to subtract and sum the value of an `input` on `mousewheel` event. The subtraction succeds, but the sum always jumps to the maximum value of the `input`. No libraries, pure JS and compatibility is irrelevant for me, since it's an Electron App.

I have another option, which I'm not entirely inclined to use, because for me, it's ugly: create a variable to sum and subtract the values,set max and min values to it and send to `input.value`(but I wasn't able to set min or max values to a variable for some reason).

Now the question: Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```js
let range = document.getElementById("test");
let onWheel = (function (evt) {
    if (!evt) evt = event;
    let wDelta;
    wDelta = evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    if (wDelta === 1) {
        range.value += wDelta;
        console.log(wDelta);
    } else {
        range.value -= 1;
        console.log(wDelta);
    }
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = range.value;
    console.log(range.value);
});

range.addEventListener('mousewheel', onWheel ,false);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="test" min="1" max="5">
<output id="out"></output>
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually a data type issue: Since `range.value` returns a string, `range.value += 1` will perform string concatenation instead of integer addition. The fix is simple:

```
range.value = parseInt(range.value) + wDelta;
```

Curiously, this only affects the addition case, because the `-` operator performs implicit integer conversion.

```js
let range = document.getElementById("test");
let onWheel = (function(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  
  let wDelta = evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  range.value = parseInt(range.value) + wDelta;

  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = range.value;
});

range.addEventListener('mousewheel', onWheel, false);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="test" min="1" max="5">
<output id="out"></output>
```

Comment: Small improvement: replace the if/else with `range.value = parseInt(range.value) + wDelta`

Answer (score -1):

The mousewheel event fires very rapidly and your range is only 1-5 so it is very difficult to only "scroll" by 1. Probably not a good use case for a 1-5 type of scenario.

Here is the code to "pad" the scroll wheel so it doesn't fire as quickly.

```js
let range = document.getElementById("test");
let padVal = false;

let onWheel = (function (evt) {
    if (!evt) evt = event;
    let wDelta;
    let min = range.min;
    let max = range.max;
    let val = range.value;
    let spread = max - min + 1;
    let pad = 100 / spread;
    
    if(padVal === false)
      padVal = val * pad;
  
    console.log(min,max,val,spread,pad,padVal,Math.floor(padVal / pad));
  
    wDelta = evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    padVal += wDelta
    range.value = Math.floor(padVal / pad);
  
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = range.value;
});

range.addEventListener('mousewheel', onWheel ,false);
```

```html
<input type="range" id="test" min="1" max="5">
<output id="out"></output>
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: And it's also wrong, the OP is converting any delta greater than 0 to be a 1, less than 0 to be a -1

Comment: @JuanMendes That's one of the reasons why it should've been a comment :)

Comment: @Armin I disagree, it should not  be an answer because it doesn't even try to answer the question, it just offers a small pointer (that is not relevant in this case) The OP can't post comments yet by the way http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Sorry, I prematurely submitted my answer before coming up with the solution. I've updated the answer with code I was working out.

Comment: @JuanMendes And that's another reason why it shouldn't be an answer :)

First version of answer was not answering OP's question, and was also wrong. Both of these things are the reason why it should've been a comment. First is obvious, but the second is also relevant. I am sure that answerer had the best intentions, but when unsure it's better to post a comment, and I've seen many incorrect comments. Sometimes they are just a part of discussion.
creativekinetix My comment was intended to help OP, and future viewers, but also to help you. These kind of comments will only get you down-votes.